# How to read and replace a line in the same file

Tags: python

I have a huge text file with multiple rows of lines. I want to read the file sequentially and whenever i locate the string assume "Apple" in any of the lines

I want to replace the entire line and not just the string "Apple".

Note: "Apple" is just a string in the line with multiple other characters.
      Replace the line with "We no more sell apples in this store".

I read that `file.readlines()` is not efficient if reading huge files. Hence please give me guidance how i can achieve this without using `readlines`.

Comment: Just how huge is "huge?"  It might help us recommend better strategies if we know how big this file is.  A few hundred kilobytes (often huge to a beginning programmer) is a much different situation than a many-gigabyte file.

Comment: Thanks Ian Mclaird for replying. The file has 600,000 lines of row..with each row of 4500 bytes length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward way would be to write a second file with your changes, then overwrite the first file.

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as ifile:
    with open(output_file, 'w') as ofile:
        for line in ifile:
            if 'Apple' in line:
                ofile.write('some other content')
            else:
                ofile.write(line)
```

Then remove the input file and rename the output file

---

The alternative is to open the file with the r+ flag and to use file.seek() to move around in the file. Something like this (I have not tested this):

```
pos = 0
with open(filename, 'r+') as fi:
    while True:
        line = fi.readline()
        if line == '': 
            break
        if 'Apple' in line:
            fi.seek(pos)  # Return to beginning of the read-in line
            fi.write(line.replace("Apple", "Orange"))  # Write new line
            fi.seek(pos)  # Return to the beginning of the written line
            line = fi.readline()  # Read to the end of the line
        pos = fi.tell()  # Fetch new position in the file
```

This is ill-advised, however, as it's error-prone. Every time that you rewrite a line you're altering the starting position of the next line, so probably what I wrote won't even work right (it's possible that you'll sometimes overwrite part of the next line if the replacement is longer than the original).

If the file is small then you should read the entire thing into memory, if the file is large then you should use a temporary file.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the response. However am aware of using the second file option. Am just looking forward to know if we can do the same without using another file.

Comment: If the length of your line changes the size of the file changes as well. Everything after your change gets a new position and has to be rewritten. This would need to happen an every changing line. Since that would be inefficient you should manipulate small files in memory and write a new file for large files.

Comment: stalsams I've updated the answer with a bit more detail